# how to add header information in ODataConsumer in odata4j?

Tags: java, odata4j

I am using this code which utilizes an odata4j `ODataClientRequest` and `ODataConsumer` to attempt to call an OData service that requires authentication:

```
    String url = "https://mylocalhost/api/odata/People()?$filter=PID%20eq%20'10'";

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("AccountID", "100");
    ODataClientRequest clientRequest = new ODataClientRequest("GET", url, headers, null, null);

    ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumer.create(url);

    for(OEntity entity : consumer.getEntities("People").execute()){
```

However, I'm getting an authentication error, because the server is requesting header authentication information. How can I create my `ODataConsumer` that includes the required authorization header information?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of manually adding a header, I believe you can use Basic Authentication (since you received an authentication error) on the client and can add a built-in client "behavior" when you set up your consumer. The code for BasicAuthenticationBehavior.java is displayed in the follwing link:

[BasicAuthenticationBehavior.java](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/odata4j/odata4j/0.4/odata4j-0.4-sources.jar!/org/odata4j/consumer/behaviors/BasicAuthenticationBehavior.java?format=ok)

The code for adding the basic authentication behavior to your `ODataConsumer` would look similar to the following:

```
ODataConsumer.Builder builder = ODataConsumers.newBuilder(url);
builder.setClientBehaviors(new BasicAuthenticationBehavior(LoginUsername, LoginPassword));      
ODataConsumer c = builder.build();

for(OEntity entity : c.getEntities("EntityName").execute()){
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty("Name").getValue().toString());
}
```